# Scala/SBT: Unresolved dependency

Tags: heroku, playframework

I'm trying to push my Play application up to heroku, which works fine in development, but Heroku's complaining that it can not found this library: [AWSScala](https://github.com/seratch/AWScala). What am I doing wrong & what can do to fix this?

Build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype Snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.github.seratch" %% "awscala" % "[0.2,)"
    )
```

Full error:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.seratch#awscala_2.10;[0.2,): not found
```

Comment: try                                                         resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.seratch" %% "awscala" % "0.2.0-SNAPSHOT"

Comment: @Gopal Now I'm getting `com.github.seratch#awscala_2.10;0.2.0-SNAPSHOT: not found`

Comment: have u added resolvers?....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The artifact is not on reposiroty Sonatype OSS Snapshots: see http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/seratch/awscala_2.10/

But it is on http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/seratch/awscala_2.10/0.2.0

So, a working build file (buit.sbt from a fresh Play Framework Project) :

```
    $ cat build.sbt
    name := "foo"

    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      jdbc,
      anorm,
      cache,
      "com.github.seratch" %% "awscala" % "[0.2,)"
    )

    play.Project.playScalaSettings
```

Resolver repo1.maven.org is include by default in sbt : see http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Resolvers.html#predefined

Comment: Ok, I removed the resolver and I'm still getting `com.github.seratch#awscala_2.10;[0.2,): not found`

Comment: Try to edit you ~/.sbt/repositories file. For example, adding this line (if it not exist) :  `maven-central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`. See this : http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Proxy-Repositories.html Which version of Scala ? (Play Framework ?)